# How can I extract CSS files from JS files with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am using Architect UI free version.
[Download Link](https://github.com/DashboardPack/architectui-html-theme-free)

I downloaded the file and When I ultimately run this command

```
npm run build
```

It generates all `html` files and an `asset` folder containing `images` and `js` files. In those `js` files `CSS` is embedded.
[image: Folder Generated after running the npm run build command]

Now I want to extract the `css` file.

How can I generate the `css` file. Let me know the step by step procedure.

I was trying to use the `mini-css-extract-plugin` plugin but failed in generating the `css` file.

Help me in this regard.

Comment: For a better understanding, can you provide an example where or how "css files are included in js files"?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the package and did a little debugging.

webpack.config.js should be the following:

```js
'use strict';
const Path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractSASS = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename:'./[name].css'});
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const pages = require('./src/pages');
let renderedPages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    let page = Object.assign({}, pages[i]);
    renderedPages.push(
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: page.template,
            filename: page.output,
            title: page.content.title,
            heading_icon: page.content.heading_icon,
            description: page.content.description
        })
    );
}

module.exports = (options) => {
    const dest = Path.join(__dirname, 'architectui-html-free');

    let webpackConfig = {
        mode: 'none',
        devtool: options.devtool,
        entry: {
            main: './src/app.js',
            demo: './src/scripts-init/demo.js',
            toastr: './src/scripts-init/toastr.js',
            scrollbar: './src/scripts-init/scrollbar.js',
            fullcalendar: './src/scripts-init/calendar.js',
            maps: './src/scripts-init/maps.js',
            chart_js: './src/scripts-init/charts/chartjs.js',
        },
        output: {
            path: dest,
            filename: './assets/scripts/[name].js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Tether: 'tether',
                'window.Tether': 'tether',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
              patterns: [
                { from: './src/assets/images', to: './assets/images' }
              ]
            }),
            new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(options.isProduction ? 'production' : 'development')
                }
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.hbs$/,
                    loader: 'handlebars-loader',
                    options: {
                        helperDirs: [
                            Path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'helpers')
                        ],
                        partialDirs: [
                            Path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'layout'),
                            Path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'DemoPages'),
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    if (options.isProduction) {
        webpackConfig.entry = [
            './src/app.js',
            './src/scripts-init/demo.js',
            './src/scripts-init/toastr.js',
            './src/scripts-init/scrollbar.js',
            './src/scripts-init/calendar.js',
            './src/scripts-init/maps.js',
            './src/scripts-init/charts/chartjs.js',

        ];

        webpackConfig.plugins.push(
            ExtractSASS,
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(/*[dest], {
                verbose: true,
                dry: false
            }*/)
        );

        webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
        });

    } else {
        webpackConfig.plugins.push(
            new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        );

        webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        );

        webpackConfig.devServer = {
            port: options.port,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: !options.isProduction,
        };

        webpackConfig.plugins.push(
            new BrowserSyncPlugin({
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3002,
                files: ["public/**/*.*"],
                browser: "google chrome",
                reloadDelay: 1000,
            }, {
                reload: false
            })
        );

    }

    webpackConfig.plugins = webpackConfig.plugins.concat(renderedPages);

    return webpackConfig;

};
```

We just changed some of the plugin definitions. Do a diff on the files to see what has changed.

Your package.json file should contain:

```js
{
  "name": "architectui-html-free",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "ArchitectUI - Free Bootstrap 5 Admin Dashboard Template",
  "author": "DashboardPack.com",
  "homepage": "https://dashboardpack.com",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack server",
    "build": "webpack --env isProduction"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/DashboardPack/architectui-html-theme-free"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
      "semi": 2
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.4",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.10.2",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.25",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.7.1",
    "metismenu": "^3.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "wnumb": "^1.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.18"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/event-stream": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.9",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.71.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

We needed to change:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack server",
    "build": "webpack --env isProduction"
  },
```

So that it runs the config.isProduction build. HTML will output the following:

```html
<script defer src="./assets/scripts/main.js"></script><link href="./main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Comment: Where should I put this code ?? Have you tried?

Comment: I downloaded the package and did some debugging, the above files work for me, after a few minor mods.